# boolean in my function didn't work for determine file size

Tags: php

I made the function for upload and I add boolean data type for determine the file extension and file size, I write the result  by javascript alert code, and then, that boolean just working for file extension validation, but not for file size validation.

What should i do? Here's some code I made:

```
function upload() {
       $namaFile = $_FILES['FOTO']['name'];
       $ukuranFile = $_FILES['FOTO']['size'];
       $error = $_FILES['FOTO']['error'];
       $tmpName = $_FILES['FOTO']['tmp_name'];

       //cek apakah tidak ada gambar yang di upload
       if ($error === 4 ) {
          echo "<script>
                alert('pilih gambar terlebih dahulu!');
               </script>";
         return false;
        }

        //cek apakah yang di upload gambar atau jenis file lain
        $ekstensiGambarValid = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
        $ekstensiGambar = explode('.', $namaFile);
        $ekstensiGambar = strtolower(end($ekstensiGambar));
        if( !in_array($ekstensiGambar, $ekstensiGambarValid)) {
        echo "<script>
            alert('hanya diperbolahkan upload file berformat jpg, jpeg, dan 
                   png saja!');
             </script>";
          return false;
          }

         //cek jika ukuran file terlalu besar
         if ( $ukuranFile > 1000000 ) {
            echo "<script>
               alert('Ukuran file terlalu besar!');
                 </script>";
           return false;
          }
}
```

I expect the output is "Ukuran file terlalu besar" //(<--this indo lang )
but the actual output is default notice I've been write on main file before.

Comment: @randomSoul: It is but that doesn't matter.  What is value of `$ukuranFile`?

Comment: @randomSoul When a numeric string and integer are compared, the string is converted to an integer, so the result should be correct.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the value is taken from the uploaded image

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung What is the actual value? What number does `echo $ukuranFile;` show?

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung No, it's a number, not a string. There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: @Barmar the echo is alert  that file size is too big and must be under 1000000

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung The question says that you expected that alert, but you're not getting it. What is the problem?

Comment: @Barmar no man, i mean the alert must be like that, like i says before, but i didn't getting it

Comment: Then I'll ask again. Add `echo $ukuranFile;` to the code, and show the output in the question.